# How can I show/hide a HTML <form> with a python (django) function?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm trying to develop a web Todo list using python (3.8.2) with django (3.0.6); I want to hide/show a HTML `<form>` using python (it is inside a `<div>` with other forms), but I really don't know how to do it. Can someone help me?

```
<form action = 'show_hide/' method = 'POST'>{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name = 'content_2' class="form-control" placeholder="Task" style = 'box-shadow: none; border-color: transparent;' autofocus wrap required>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark mt-2 mb-2" name = 'edit' onclick = 'edit_task()'>Edit Task</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can send a variable from your views.py and wrap your code in an if statement as below:

```
{% if variable %}
<form action = 'show_hide/' method = 'POST'>{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name = 'content_2' class="form-control" placeholder="Task" style = 'box-shadow: none; border-color: transparent;' autofocus wrap required>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark mt-2 mb-2" name = 'edit' onclick = 'edit_task()'>Edit Task</button>
</form>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example?